# Mailing Server Error: stream_socket_enable_crypto

Tags: php, ssl, phpmailer, phabricator

My application which utilized PHPMailer used to work on PHP V5.5.x. On the older version i did not have to issue any certificate to send an email, and it ran on tls protocol at port 25 (at least that is the settings in the application).

But, once I have upgraded the system to v7.1.x, the mailing system stopped sending out email.

I am using the email application in house between multiple computer with in house SMTP mailing server.
It seems that i am having certificate issues, and i am guessing the new PHPMailer probably requires a certificate. Did not use to.

So, i created a self-signed certificate by generating a key, csr, and .key.

Couple of questions on the self-signed certificate.

1. Does the CN need to match with what the mailing server CN is?
2. Do I set the "Common Name" to match the IP address of my server address: 10.10.10.100

Here is the error log, that might help for assistance.

```
User@debian:/opt/myApps/apps/phabricator/htdocs$ ./bin/phd log
Daemon 6214 INIT [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:21 -0400] Starting process.
Daemon 6214 ZZZZ [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:21 -0400] Process is preparing to hibernate for 180 second(s).
Daemon 6214 DONE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:21 -0400] Process exited normally.
Daemon 6214 WAIT [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:21 -0400] Waiting 180 second(s) to restart process.
Daemon 6215 INIT [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:26 -0400] Starting process.
Daemon 6215 ZZZZ [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:26 -0400] Process is preparing to hibernate for 180 second(s).
Daemon 6215 DONE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:26 -0400] Process exited normally.
Daemon 6215 WAIT [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:38:26 -0400] Waiting 180 second(s) to restart process.
Daemon 6216 WAKE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:08 -0400] Process is being awakened from hibernation.
Daemon 6216 INIT [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:08 -0400] Starting process.


Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400] [2018-04-17 19:39:09] ERROR 2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.company.com' did not match expected CN=`10.10.10.5' at [/opt/myApps/apps/phabricator/htdocs/externals/phpmailer/class.smtp.php:197]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400] arcanist(head=stable, ref.stable=7b6a9a93f4a4), phabricator(head=stable, ref.stable=5e710959bed9), phutil(head=stable, ref.stable=47cfa511ca67)
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #0 stream_socket_enable_crypto(resource, boolean, integer) called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.smtp.php:197]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #1 SMTP::StartTLS() called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:787]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #2 PHPMailer::SmtpConnect() called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:689]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #3 PHPMailer::SmtpSend(string, string) called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:576]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #4 PHPMailer::Send() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/adapter/PhabricatorMailImplementationPHPMailerAdapter.php:159]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #5 PhabricatorMailImplementationPHPMailerAdapter::send() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:605]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #6 PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendWithMailers(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:491]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #7 PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendNow() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker.php:22]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #8 PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker::doWork() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php:123]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #9 PhabricatorWorker::executeTask() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/storage/PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask.php:171]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #10 PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask::executeTask() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon.php:22]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #11 PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon::run() called at [<phutil>/src/daemon/PhutilDaemon.php:219]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #12 PhutilDaemon::execute() called at [<phutil>/scripts/daemon/exec/exec_daemon.php:131]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400] [2018-04-17 19:39:09] EXCEPTION: (PhutilProxyException) Error while executing Task ID 9840. {>} (phpmailerException) Language string failed to load: tls at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:788]


Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400] arcanist(head=stable, ref.stable=7b6a9a93f4a4), phabricator(head=stable, ref.stable=5e710959bed9), phutil(head=stable, ref.stable=47cfa511ca67)
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #0 <#2> PHPMailer::SmtpConnect() called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:689]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #1 <#2> PHPMailer::SmtpSend(string, string) called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php:576]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #2 <#2> PHPMailer::Send() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/adapter/PhabricatorMailImplementationPHPMailerAdapter.php:159]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #3 <#2> PhabricatorMailImplementationPHPMailerAdapter::send() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:605]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #4 <#2> PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendWithMailers(array) called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:491]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #5 <#2> PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendNow() called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker.php:22]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #6 <#2> PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker::doWork() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php:123]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #7 <#2> PhabricatorWorker::executeTask() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/storage/PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask.php:171]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #8 <#2> PhabricatorWorkerActiveTask::executeTask() called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon.php:22]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #9 PhabricatorTaskmasterDaemon::run() called at [<phutil>/src/daemon/PhutilDaemon.php:219]
Daemon 6216 STDE [Tue, 17 Apr 2018 19:39:09 -0400]   #10 PhutilDaemon::execute() called at [<phutil>/scripts/daemon/exec/exec_daemon.php:131]
```

Comment: It’s not PHPMailer that requires a valid certificate, it’s PHP itself. This changed in PHP 5.6. Please read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide which goes into great detail on this.

Comment: What file changed in PHP 5.6 that enforced this certification validation? Currently, I am using in house through intranet. Nothing is going out of the building. And i guess i still cannot bypassed it like before PHP 5.6?

Comment: Read the guide, it tells you what you can do.